# Various interfaces for a single "data-carrying" class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a series of classes that provide a (common) interface to triangular or symmetric matrices, but I want to avoid copying memory (i.e. make a lot of in-place operations).

The way I was thinking to do this in C++ is to implement a class or struct that is simply a vector containing the matrix data (since I am only concerned on triangular matrices, I only have to store half of the matrix approx.). Let's call this "data-carrying" class **`SquareTriangularMatrix`**. Now the data inside this matrix could be accessed differently depending wether the data should be treated as upper triangular, lower triangular or even symmetric.

I do not think that polymorphism can be applied in my case because I want that the same object of **`SquareTriangularMatrix`** have different interfaces depending on the context. Some times **`SquareTriangularMatrix`** could be treated as a lower triangular matrix, but some others might be its transpose: an upper triangular matrix, and so on.

Is there any design pattern that addresses this problem? Any hint or guideline in this context would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Just some thoughts: I would go for composition over inheritance. If the different matrix types are really supposed to have different interfaces, exposing a base class interface might be more confusing than it helps. On the other hand you might want to use the same algorithm with different types of matrices, which would be easier if they do share the same interface.

Comment: This sounds like a [Flyweight](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create adapter classes for your storage class, like that:

```
struct SquareTriangularMatrix {
    // constructor, maybe operator[], etc
    int* values;
    int nrows;
    int ncolumns;
};

struct UpperTriangleMatrix {
    UpperTriangleMatrix (SquareTriangularMatrix& data): data(data) {}
    int at (unsigned row, unsigned column) const {
        if (row > column) return 0;
        return data.values [row * data.ncolumns + column];
    }
private:
    SquareTriangularMatrix& data;
};
```

Then you can make that class `UpperTriangleMatrix` nested in the `SquareTriangularMatrix` and add a function like `SquareTriangularMatrix::as_upper()` which will return that adapter constructed with this matrix.

Another way you can go is to create a function `as` in the `SquareTriangularMatrix` that will allow to add custom adapters later, like this:

```
struct SquareTriangularMatrix {
    //...
    template <class T> T
    as () { return T(*this); }
};

//usage:
SquareTriangularMatrix m;
auto upper = m.as <UpperTriangleMatrix>();
```

Using this approach, you can convert your matrix at any moment to any adapter you wish that satisfies the `as` template (which is pretty simple and broad), and extend the list of adapters in any file locally.

You can also follow the way STL allows to convert time (`std::duration_cast`):

```
template <typename T> T& matrix_cast (SquareTriangularMatrix& m) { return T(m); }

SquareTriangularMatrix m;
auto upper = matrix_cast <UpperTriangleMatrix>(m);
```

It works just the same way as the function `as<>` from the previous sample, it's only a matter of taste.